# TFS Web access "client cache" (2015.2 on-premise)

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem, workitem, tfs-web-access

Web Access do Something like "client cache" when i open a Work Item edit Form

1st open : Web Access call TFS API to update all fields (ex : http://TFSServeur:8080/tfs/Collection/_api/_wit/workitems?__v=5&ids=8779)

2nd open : Web Access not call TFS API

An idea to always call API ? Somthing in TFS Web Access config ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no way to do it in TFS 2015.2. You need to click refresh button to refresh the work item.

BTW: There is [refresh()](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/api/tfs/workitemtracking/services/workitemformservice#refresh) method that can call it in [onLoaded](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-workitem-extension#events) event, but it isn’t applied for TFS 2015.2. (Works fine in Visual Studio Team Services)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that via Web Access directly.

To update the fields the http needs to be a "**PATCH** " request. When you open a url in a browser directly, those are "**Get**" requests.

So, you can update the work items use a web development tool (such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)) that lets you specify the http **PATCH** request method. It's not "client cache" but really update.

Please see the [REST API to Update work items](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#update-work-items) for details.

[image]